# Follow linked list in OCL

Tags: ocl, bold-delphi

I use Bold for Delphi that has an implementation of [OCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language). OCL is good at filtering lists, etc. But I have not found a good, generic way of traversing linked lists.

Suppose I have a class `PlanMission`. It contains a single link `PlanMission.previous` that points to itself. It also has a boolean attribute `isDummy`.

I want to traverse a list of `PlanMissions` until I have an instance with `isDummy`.

I can do

```
if isdummy then
  self
else if previous->notEmpty and previous.isdummy then
  previous
else if previous.previous->notEmpty and previous.previous.isdummy then
  previous.previous
else
  nil
endif
endif
endif
```

What I really want is something like this:

```
traverseList(previous, isDummy)
```

`traverseList` does not exist, but it should have 2 parameters.

- `previous`: The link to follow
- `isDummy`: A boolean condition so I know when to stop

How can this be accomplished?

**Edit clarification**
I don't want any Delphi code. I want code in [OCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language). Those that use [Bold](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23890) know what I mean. OCL is a query language with query objects, attributes, etc. It is free of side effects, so it is readonly. Introduction to OCL can be found [here.](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32200)

Comment: I don't get it. You want to do this in Delphi? How odes OCL come into play?

Comment: @jpfollenius Is he asking for: teh codez plz??

Comment: No delphi code, it is trivial in Delphi. OCL is very different from Delphi. It often used in modeldriven development. Bold for Delphi have one implementation of OCL.

Comment: Deleted my answer. But how is traversing a linked list an object constraint? All the examples I see of OCL look nothing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute the ordered transitive closure of the `previous` relationship. 
(self, self.previous, self.previous.previous, etc.)

In OCL 2.3.1 it is `self->asOrderedSet()->closure(previous)`

then you may extract the first dummy `PlanMission` (or null if there is none) by:

```
let c:Set(PlanMission) = 
  self->asOrderedSet()->closure(previous)->select(x|x.isDummy) in
  if c->isEmpty() then null else select(x|x.isDummy)->first()
```

In section 11.9 *Mapping Rules for Predefined Iterator Expressions* of [OCL 2.3.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1) there is a definition of `closure` in terms of `iterate` that you may use if your tool supports an older version of OCL.